# google maps API v3, marker icon has transparent padding, how do I position it counting this padding?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use custom marker Icon for google Maps. My problem is simple, transparent png that I prepared has extra 23px of empty space at the bottom - this is done for some photoshop glow effect, but an actual point of marker starts at 23px from bottom.

How do I take this into consideration so that marker lands on the right spot? I need something like margin-bottom:-23px; but with javascript.

Hard way would be to calculate 23px in latlong measures and than adjust marker position. But that would be insanely ugly...

Any ideas?

so far I've this:

```
var marker_icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('<?php echo get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/images/marker.png', new google.maps.Point(10,10));
                                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                  position: latlngPos,
                                  map: map,
                                  icon: marker_icon
                                });
```

but since I changed icon: to the variable, I don't see marker anymore. Console tells me nothing.

image is this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation on how to define a [custom Icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon)

> anchor | Point | The position at which to anchor an image in correspondance to the location of the marker on the map. By default, the anchor is located along the center point of the bottom of the image.
>
> url | string | The URL of the image or sprite sheet.
> google.maps.MarkerShape object specification

It is computed from the top left corner of the image (0, 0).  But you haven't provided the size.

[Developers Guide (with example)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#ComplexIcons)

Your image is 59px × 72px
So I think the anchor should be 72-23: new google.maps.Point(30,49);

```
var marker_icon = {
   url: <your url>,
   size: new google.maps.Size(59,72),
   origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
   anchor: new google.maps.Point(30,49)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to do it this way:

```
var marker_icon = {
                                      url: '<?php echo get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/images/marker.png',
                                      size: new google.maps.Size(59,72),
                                      origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                                      anchor: new google.maps.Point(29,58)
                                    };
```

Thank you geocodezip for the direction.