# Custom image icon not positioning

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I know this sounds duplicate but when I searched here in SO it doesn't help me. my problem is that I have custom icon or image the dimension is 256 x 256, scaledSize this to 50, now the problem is that it does not properly positioning to the latlng. also the problem is that when I zoom the map the marker will move or it will go away to it's position... unlike this example it work's fine
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex .

Here is my code

```
 var imageicon= {
                url:  '/image/' + filename, // url
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50), // scaled size
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 50) // anchor
            };


 custommarker= new google.maps.Marker({
                flat: true,
                icon: imageicon,
                map: map,
                optimized: false,
                position: coordinate,
                visible: true
            });
```

Here is my marker

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps marker positioning with custom icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057920/google-maps-marker-positioning-with-custom-icon)

Comment: possible duplicate of [google maps API v3, marker icon has transparent padding, how do I position it counting this padding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525848/google-maps-api-v3-marker-icon-has-transparent-padding-how-do-i-position-it-co)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps: Custom Marker Icon - Not plotting at Center of Rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39141554/google-maps-custom-marker-icon-not-plotting-at-center-of-rectangle)

Comment: @geocodezip, if this is my latlng 38.781576, -97.617363 and my dimenesion of my image 256x256..and want to be scaled to 50x50..what would be my anchor ? or how can I plot that the image should be in the right position of my latlng ?

Comment: I tried 0,25 as my anchor but seems always not in the right position when I am zooming the map

Comment: Where the anchor should be depends on the icon.  A circle would most likely have the anchor in the middle, a "bubble/pointer" would have it where ever the point is.  You haven't provided your icon, so we can't tell you what it should be for your map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your icon is 50px by 50px.  You currently have the anchor set to (0,50) (the bottom left corner of the icon).  You want the anchor set to the "point" at the bottom center (25,50)

```
var imageicon = {
  url: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEvED.png', // url
  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50), // scaled size
  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(25, 50) // anchor
};
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/je2Lda4p/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: { // New York, NY
      lat: 40.7127753,
      lng: -74.0059728
    },
    zoom: 7
  });
  var imageicon = {
    url: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEvED.png', // url
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50), // scaled size
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(25, 50) // anchor
  };

  var custommarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    flat: true,
    icon: imageicon,
    map: map,
    optimized: false,
    position: map.getCenter(),
    visible: true
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk">
</script>
```